# UK tourist visa refused twice

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

I have been refused UK visa twice, reasons being;

1.I have no sufficient funds to fund my trip Even though my sponsor who is my long time friend and who had invited me had indicated in the invitation letter that she Will cater for my transport,accomodation etc for the two weeks I was to be there.

2.My income is modest.

3.I didn't demonstrate any significant strong personal ties to my home country.

Last I applied was in August 2017.I want to apply again this year,what do I need to do especially about reason number 3? someone kindly advise me.
I'm single lady aged 37 yes old.I have been thinking of doing a nice cover letter,what and how should I write the cover letter if that is the case? Thanks so much.

Comment: Why do you want to return to your home country? The entry clearance officer will evaluate your application with this in mind. If you do not provide a good answer, your visa is likely to be refused.

Comment: Thanks,but what answer can I give? considering that I gave my birthday certificate and my land ownership certificate but still they gave me this reason.My circumstance for reason 1&2 have improved,only reason number 3 to work on.

Comment: Please upload a scan of the refusal letter, after blanking out any personal information.

Comment: Do you have a job or run a business? Do you have anyone dependent on you like children, siblings or parents/grandparents? That's the kind of things they're looking for.

Comment: There’s no need to upload a scan of your refusal. It’s unnecessary. We’ve seen enough of those and from your summary and it definitely falls under one of the three or four canonical answers we have for UK visa refusals. Nothing unique about your case. Start at https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e and use the search function for the others.

Comment: @mkennedy,I have a small business now,I have siblings and elderly parents,I had given them the evidence of my land ownership (land title deed.).I don't have children but I have siblings and parents,do I need to show the evidence?for example giving out their birth/identity certificates?

Comment: So my question is,how best can I write a cover letter indicating that I have siblings and parents here who are dependent to me for the purpose of demonstrating my strong ties to my home country?because I already filled in the application form the details of my parents as requested.